# md-icon' is not a known element ERROR while working with Angular Material 8.2.3 even though imported --

Tags: angular, npm, material-design, angular8, angular-material-7

a quick query --

Am using angular-material 8.2.3 in my angular 8 app - getting the following error wrt md-icon.

> 'md-icon' is not a known element:
>       1. If 'md-icon' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

this html --

```html
<div class="image-picker" (click)="fileInput.click()">
   <mat-icon [class.small]="imageUrl">file_upload</mat-icon>
   <canvas width="500" height="380" #canvas hidden="true"></canvas>
   <input #fileInput type="file" hidden="true" (change)="imageDataChanged($event)">
</div>
```

I have in my app.module.ts file the following line --

```js
import { MatInputModule, MatButtonModule, MatSelectModule, MatIconModule, MatCardModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and in imports section `MatIconModule` mentioned clearly.

Any clue what's missing or what may be wrong here?? If you observe in the html I pasted, it is mat-icon. Originally that was `md-icon` and I changed that to try out. Neither did the trick. I hope I have imported the correct package.

Can you tell me what exactly it is? What did I do incorrect?

My NgModule code --

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    BasicLayoutComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    RegistrationComponent,
    CameraSnapshotComponent,
    ImagePickerComponent,
    BlockUIComponent,
    UpdateImageComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    FormsModule,
    MatInputModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatSelectModule,
    MatIconModule,
    MatCardModule
  ],
  exports:
    [
      MatInputModule,
      MatButtonModule,
      MatSelectModule,
      MatIconModule,
      MatCardModule
    ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

Comment: Could you update your question with your `NgModule` code

Comment: The posted code doesn't have any `md-icon` element. So either the message is different from what you posted, or the code is different from what you posted, or the error is caused by some other code than the one you posted, which does have an `md-icon` element.

Comment: hi @C_Ogoo updated, pl take a look,

Comment: hi @JBNizet  I explained that in the 3rd main stanza of my question,

Comment: So, do you still get that precise and exact message, or not? If you don't, then post the actual message you get. If you still do, then fix the code that still contains an `md-icon` element.

Comment: @PrabirChoudhury search for all occurences of `md-icon` in your codebase. Also restart your dev server if you havent already

Comment: Yes, in both cases the same error message !!   @JBNizet    Baffling !!  Ok, that's a good pointer, I'll do a search if any more occurrences,

Comment: Again, that most probably means that some **other** code still using md-icon is causing that error. Find it and fix it. Or that you forgot to save the changes to you file. Or that you're not editing the file you think is used by the CLI. Or that the CLI needs to be restarted.

Comment: Yes, there was another instance of md-icon in another file. Also, I stopped and restarted CLI angular server. That error is now gone.     @JBNizet